# Highlighting a specific point of a geom_point ggplot chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to `ggplot` and I am trying to create `geom_point` chart and highlight one of the point from the chart.

Right now I am using the following code to generate the point chart

```
p <- ggplot(, aes(x=(dd$time), y=dd$val, group=dd$val)) + geom_hline(yintercept=mag$val)  
p + geom_jitter(aes(colour = dd$amount))
p + geom_point(aes(size = dd$amount))
```

Initially I wanted to create a cross over the point that is why you see `geom_hline(yintercept=mag$val)` on the code, but when I add `geom_vline(xintercept = (mag$time))` there is no vertical line displayed.

What would be the appropriate way to highlight the point given by `x=mag$time` and `y=mag$val` in the same chart with my `dd` data?

Any tip in the right direction will be appreciated, 
Thanks

Comment: just subset you dataset for the point you want and add a new geom_point(data=singledata, aes(x=x, y=x), colour="differentcolor", shape"differentshape"). Should be enough to highlight the point.

Comment: @MLavoie, Hi! thanks, the thing is that when I add `p + geom_point(data=mag, aes(x=mag$time, y=mag$val), colour="green")` I get a chart with only that point instead of all the points and that one highlighted.

Comment: You've misread @MLavoie's suggestion. He's suggesting (accurately) that you use layers. The first layer is all points but the highlighted point, the second layer is the highlighted point.

Comment: try: ggplot() + geom_point(data=dd, aes(x=time, y=val, group=val, size=amount)) + geom_point(data=mag, aes(x=mag$time, y=mag$val), colour="green")

Comment: @MLavoie got it! thanks! I was not aware of how layers work, I thought that `p +` was infact adding a layer to the plot. Thanks

Comment: Also to mention, do not use `dataframe$varname` within `aes` as it can lead to unexpected results - just use `varname` and `data=dataframe`